# Chrome Remote Desktop stopped working after configuring a wireguard tunnel from my local server to oracle OCI VPS

Tags: chrome-remote-desktop

Here is the setup:

Local Server: Ubuntu OS 22.04 as a wireguard client to Oracle Cloud Instance VPS.

Cloud Server: Ubuntu OS 22.04 as a wireguard server for my local server which is behind cgnat.  There is also a nginx reverse proxy allowing services on my local server to be accessible from the net.

After I successfully installed the tunnel, i noticed that my chrome remote desktop isn't working. Here are some details  for the local server:

```
$ sudo systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop.service
○ chrome-remote-desktop.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit chrome-remote-desktop.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)

$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
32400/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
63727/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
3389/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
5900 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
63727/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
32400/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3389/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

$ sudo cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ----
Address = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128
DNS = 1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = ----
PresharedKey = ----
Endpoint = vpspublixIP:63727
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0

Here is the cloud server info:
```

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
32400/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
32480/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
32400/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
32480/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.66.66.1/24,fd42:42:42::1/64
ListenPort = 63727
PrivateKey = ----
PostUp = iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 63727 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i enp0s6 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s6 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s6 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -p udp --dport 63727 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i enp0s6 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp0s6 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp0s6 -j MASQUERADE

### Client plex
[Peer]
PublicKey = ----
PresharedKey = ----
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128
```

I've tried rerunning the installation command for chrome remote desktop and it gives me this error:

```
Enter a PIN of at least six digits:
Enter the same PIN again:
[0312/165119.323881:INFO:host_stopper.cc(37)] Stopping existing host: 8197c081-1c13-4c2e-8496-b09e04efeb06. This may take a few seconds.
[0312/165119.810885:ERROR:service_client.cc(132)] Received error code: 7, message: Forbidden
[0312/165130.029790:INFO:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(97)] Killing process 767

[0312/165130.334171:ERROR:service_client.cc(132)] Received error code: 7, message: Forbidden
Couldn't start host: OAuth error.
```

I am not sure what should be done. I have not tried reinstalling.